# Why does a variable assignment in a loop before a continue statement count as never read?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings

On the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut i: Option<i32> = None;

    let mut cond = true;
    while true && i.map_or(true, |x| x < 10) {
        if cond {
            cond = false;
            i = Some(0);
            continue;
        }
        i = Some(5);
    } 
}
```

I get the warning:

```
warning: value assigned to `i` is never read
 --> src/lib.rs:8:13
  |
8 |             i = Some(0);
  |             ^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_assignments)] on by default
```

This is very minimized (so please ignore for the moment that it'll loop forever), but shows the issue: the compiler seems to think that `i` from inside the `if` is overwritten by the outer assignment, which is clearly not the case due to the `continue`.

Am I missing something and have I introduced a bug of some description into the program, or is it the compiler's mistake?

Comment: You do not need to put the type of `i`. Because of the line `i = Some(0)`, the compiler knows that `i` is `Option<i32>`

Comment: Since this is a compiler bug, you could perhaps just live with the warning, or suppress it in this instance with `#[allow(unused_assignments)]` on the containing function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is not well aware of the flow break controls [because of a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22630). If you can, you should use an expression oriented syntax that is more idiomatic:

```
fn main() {
    let mut i = None;

    let mut cond = true;
    while true && i.map_or(true, |x| x < 10) {
        i = if cond {
            cond = false;
            Some(0)
        } else {
            Some(5)
        }
    } 
}
```

or create a custom iterator.

Comment: Hm, I'll try to do something like that, but that's going to be convoluted, to say the least. The actual code has some `return`s and `if let`s, which complicates expression extraction somewhat.